# Licensing fee for BDB (Berkeley DB)

Tags: license

Does anyone know how much Oracle charges for using BDB (Berkeley Database) in a dual-licensed open-source+commercial application?

While Tokyo Cabinet (http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet) provides a similar key-value DB like BDB, it lacks some features like replication, custom recovery logs and checkpointing which BDB has. Oracle on its part has made it very difficult to determine BDB licensing (we have to go through a sales rep and it is taking way too long).

- Sorry for the cross-post with Serverfault, but it isn't clear whether this question belongs here or at Serverfault! *

Comment: I'm sorry, but if Oracle can't tell you, some random dude on a forum won't be able to do any better. This is a business question, not technical in any way, doesn't really belong on either of these two sites.

Comment: If you work for a large company, call the main number, ask for your company's corporate rep at Oracle- not the sales rep. Then tell him the sales rep is taking too long. If not, ask for the head of small business sales, tell him you want to give him money but the sales rep is too slow. High performance will then ensue.

Answer (score 2):

> For pricing information, or if you
>   have further questions on licensing,
>   please contact us at
>   berkeleydb-info_us@oracle.com

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/berkeley-db/htdocs/licensing.html

Comment: Contact them, they are more likely to give you a straight answer than we are.